# Use recursion to count the number of lists with odd length or even length in a nested list

Tags: java, algorithm, list, recursion, nested

How can I write a recursive method in Java that takes in a nested list and counts out the number of list with odd length and the number of list with even length? So far I only got this:

```
public class MyRekursion {
    // [number of odd-lengthed lists, number of even-lengthed lists]
    public static int[] countOddEven(List<Object> nestedList) {
        int odd = 0;
        int even = 0;
        for (Object obj : nestedList){
            if (obj instanceof List){
                // ???
            }
        }

        return new int[] { odd, even };
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the reason for for loop when you have to recurse? Instead add three parameters i.e. netxElementToGet (with value as size of nestedList - 1), evenCount and odd count, when you encounter that nextElementToGet is 0, just return even and odd count as an array.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyRecursion {
    public static int[] countOddEven(List nestedList) {
        int odd = 0;
        int even = 0;

        for (Object obj : nestedList) {
            if (obj instanceof List) {
                int[] res = countOddEven((List)obj);
                odd += res[0];
                even += res[1];
            }
        }

        if (nestedList.size() % 2 == 1) {
            ++odd;
        } else {
            ++even;
        }

        return new int[] { odd, even };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should replace your /?? because %2 gives the rest value when you devide by 2 (modulus). So if this equals 0, it's even, else it's uneven

```
if ((obj.size() % 2) == 0 {
     even++;
     }else{
      odd++;
 }
}
```